# position: absolute; moves images in front of a div

Tags: html, css

I have two images that need to be at the bottom of a div and behind a gradient that needs to have the same rules both can be fixed with `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` but it moves the images in front of the gradient

The reason for this approach is that I need the page to be responsive with different resolutions for PCs

[How it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXJ64.png)

[How I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlQcF.png)

Gradient CSS Code:

```css
.gradient {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000, transparent);
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 43.5%;
    height: 13.8%;
}
```

Images CSS Code:

```css
.images {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 4% 0 0 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Html of the whole page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.png">
    <title>Creature Cult</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="gradient"></div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <img src="banner.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Socials</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="explore">
            <img src="explore.png" alt="explore" class="explore">
        </div>
        <div class="arrow">
            <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrowBTN">
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <img src="rabbit.png" alt="rabbit" class="rabbit">    
            <img src="penguin.png" alt="penguin" class="penguin">
        </div> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="about">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74006196/edit) to show your HTML.

Comment: Why not just add the `.gradient` class to your `<div class="images">` and remove the `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` rules?

Comment: @kmoser Because the position: absolute and bottom: 0 rules are the whole point I need. I need both divs the be at the bottom of the main div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `z-index` on `.gradient` (z index 1) `.images` (z index 0) in order to fix display layers order